# Sharepoint PNP Core C# How to access Client Page Web Properties array

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365

Hey all I have been working on this all day today and I can't seem to figure it out.  I am not real great with C# and more of just kind of a hobyist.  What I am trying to accomplish is to get the values that are inside of the json array called sites.  I can pull the title, all the properties etc... I just dont know how to access the property that is an array.  When I try to run the values I get returned a Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JEnumerable`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.  I have also tested if the key "sites" has values and it returns true.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
        private void btnGetLists_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = ConnectPNP();
        var web = context.Web;
        //context.Load(web, w => w.Lists);            
        context.ExecuteQueryRetry();

        var sitepages = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Site Pages");
        var item = sitepages.GetItemById(1);
        context.Load(item, i => i.File);
        context.ExecuteQueryRetry();

        var file = item.File;
        var page = ClientSidePage.Load(context, file.Name);            
        var webParts = page.Controls.FindAll(x => x.Type.Name == "ClientSideWebPart");
        
        foreach (var part in webParts)
        {
            var parttoshow = (ClientSideWebPart)part;
            var myWebPart = parttoshow.Properties;

            Console.WriteLine(myWebPart.Values());

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Timg,

I tested your code in my environment. The `ClientSideWebPart.Properties` is a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`.

[image]

Think you can use [Item[String]](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm) to get its value. To get the inside array, you may take a reference of:

- https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm